# Hibernate: Sorting by a field from a linked table if foreign key is null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, sorting

Lets say I have two tables - "Cat" and "Cat owner" that are linked with many-to-one like this:

```
<class name="com.example.Cat" table="cat">
        ... 
        <many-to-one name="owner"
            class="com.example.CatOwner"
            column="owner_id" 
            not-null="false" insert="true" update="true" cascade="none" lazy="false"/>
</class>
```

Now I want to get a list of all cats sorted by cat owner names, like this:

```
session.createQuery("from Cat cat order by cat.owner.name");
```

The problem is if a cat doesn't have an owner (owner_id=NULL), that cat won't be selected with this query. How can I make cats without owners to be present in the result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Hibernate docs, [14.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins). Your query should be something like:

```
 from Cat cat left join cat.owner owner order by owner.name
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL it's a typical example of an OUTER JOIN, so the fast answer is trying to write the query like:

```
session.createQuery("select cat from Cat cat, CatOwner cato WHERE cato.id(+) = cat.ownerId order by cato.name NULLS LAST");
```

NOTE: I have not tested the posted code!
NOTE2: I suppose an Oracle RDBMS and hibernate.properties properly configured.